# Does the given sentence become grammatically incorrect when you remove the word "as?" Also, does the meaning change when you remove the same word?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality, ellipsis

Check as many articles **as** you're comfortable checking.

Check as many articles you're comfortable checking.

Is the second sentence grammartically incorrect? Does it mean the same thing as the first sentence?
Can the second **as** in the first sentence be ommitted?

Answer (score 1):

Comparative expressions of the form **as** [something] **as** [something else] need to have both the first 'as' and the second 'as'.

> The world’s biggest dog is as big as a small horse.
>
> The weather this summer is as bad as last year.
>
> You have to unwrap it as carefully as you can.

You cannot remove either of the two occurrences of 'as'.

[As... as (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as)